# Sign-changing solutions for initial-boundary value problem for $\partial_t u + \partial^4_x u = 0$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Can you point out a reference for the fact that solutions for the initial-boundary value problem associated to $$\partial_t u + \partial^4_x u = 0$$ with $u(0,\cdot) >0$ can change sign (that is, need not be positive)?

Comment: How do you prove such a claim?

Answer (score 3):

For a delta-function initial condition, $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$, the solution follows upon Fourier transformation,
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-k^4 t} \cos kx\,dk .$$
This is a hypergeometric function which oscillates around zero, see the plot of $u(x,t)$ for $t=0.01,0.1,1$.

[image]

The delta-function initial condition is not strictly positive, but we can alternatively choose a gaussian $u(x,0)=\exp(-ax^2)$ upon convolution:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-ax'^2}e^{-k^4 t} \cos k(x-x')\,dk dx'.$$
The sign change persists, see plot for $a=10$, $t=0.01$.

[image]

---

The OP asks for a reference, for example, the figure above is similar to figure 1 of [this 2008 paper.](http://www.mdpi.org/entropy/papers/e10030365.pdf)

Comment: It seems the cosine in the integrand is the one causing the change sign, irrelevant of the positive initial function. I don't why there would be a specific first reference that discusses this problem.

Comment: @Alan ---no, it's not that trivial; suppose you replace the $k^4$ in the exponent by $k^2$; the cosine is still there, but now it is indeed true that a positive initial distribution remains positive; that is just what you would expect for a diffusion equation, the density cannot become negative; so it is somewhat remarkable that by going from second derivative with respect to $x$ to fourth derivative the positivity is lost.

Comment: How do you then prove these two claims in your last comment?

Comment: you mean a proof that the solution of the diffusion equation $\partial_t u-\partial_x^2 u=0$ stays positive for all times? this follows from the fact that the Fourier transform with respect to $k$ of $e^{-k^2 t}$ is again a Gaussian, and the convolution of any positive initial distribution with a Gaussian remains positive. Replacing the $k^2$ by $k^4$ spoils that, you get this hypergeometric function that changes sign.

Comment: How do you prove that the convolution of any initial positive distribution with a Gaussian remains positive?

Comment: the integrand is positive, so the integral must also be positive: $u(x,t)=t^{-1/2}\int u(x',0)\exp[(x-x')^2/4t]\,dx'>0$ when $u(x,0)>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have some related questions: **1.** For any PDE: why is it legitimate to apply Fourier transform? You don't know a priori the regularity of the solution. **2.** What kind of boundary conditions do you need to impose in your example? **3** Are those plots done with Mathematica? What code did you use to produce them? Thanks again.

Comment: 1) if you allow for distributions (delta functions) this is OK; 2) integrable solution on $\mathbb{R}$; 3) yes indeed, but it's a trivial integral, you can also plot it on Wolfram Alpha.